# Google calendar implementation on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, google-calendar-api

I want to implement Google calendar grid view link on iPhone using GData. So I successfully implemented and accessed my Google account through GData. But I can see all the events in a TableView structure... I want the structure as in the following screenshot.

[image]

How i can get this view?

I downloaded the demo app from [this link](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/).

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Abizern, lol. Can u read all question. I already wrote i m tried and implemented in Tableview ...

Comment: I want suggestion..... it is ok if any body haven't answer of it

Comment: you say you've implemented in a tableview - but you seem to be asking about how to create a grid-view. That's what I'm asking about. Which bit of creating a grid view are you having trouble with?

Comment: have u implemented google calendar in swift

Answer (score 2):

Hi is there one third party API to display calender like that..

i show some code here

Implementation for Week,

```
- (MAEvent *)event {
static int counter;

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"number %i", counter++] forKey:@"test"];

MAEvent *event = [[MAEvent alloc] init];
event.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
event.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
event.allDay = NO;
event.userInfo = dict;
return event;
}


- (void)weekView:(MAWeekView *)weekView eventTapped:(MAEvent *)event {
NSDateComponents *components = [CURRENT_CALENDAR components:DATE_COMPONENTS fromDate:event.start];
NSString *eventInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hour %i. Userinfo: %@", [components hour], [event.userInfo objectForKey:@"test"]];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:event.title
                                                 message:eventInfo delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
}
```

Implementation for  Day..
tatic NSDate *date = nil;

```
- (NSArray *)dayView:(MADayView *)dayView eventsForDate:(NSDate *)startDate 
{
date = startDate;

NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: self.event, self.event, self.event,
                self.event, self.event, self.event, self.event,  self.event, self.event, nil];
static size_t generateAllDayEvents;

generateAllDayEvents++;

if (generateAllDayEvents % 4 == 0)
{
    ((MAEvent *) [arr objectAtIndex:0]).title = @"All-day events test";
    ((MAEvent *) [arr objectAtIndex:0]).allDay = YES;
    ((MAEvent *) [arr objectAtIndex:1]).title = @"All-day events test";
    ((MAEvent *) [arr objectAtIndex:1]).allDay = YES;
}
return arr;
}

 - (MAEvent *)event {
static int counter;
static BOOL flag;

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"number %i", counter++] forKey:@"test"];

unsigned int r = arc4random() % 24;
int rr = arc4random() % 3;

MAEvent *event = [[MAEvent alloc] init];
event.backgroundColor = ((flag = !flag) ? [UIColor purpleColor] : [UIColor brownColor]);
event.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
event.allDay = NO;
event.userInfo = dict;

if (rr == 0) {
    event.title = @"Event lorem ipsum es dolor test. This a long text, which should clip the event view bounds.";
} else if (rr == 1) {
    event.title = @"Foobar.";
} else {
    event.title = @"Dolor test.";
}

NSDateComponents *components = [CURRENT_CALENDAR components:DATE_COMPONENTS fromDate:date];
[components setHour:r];
[components setMinute:0];
[components setSecond:0];

event.start = [CURRENT_CALENDAR dateFromComponents:components];

[components setHour:r+rr];
[components setMinute:0];

event.end = [CURRENT_CALENDAR dateFromComponents:components];

return event;
 }
```